# SSMS Edit Rows with Intellisense or Edit Query results directly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, intellisense, ssms

We know when writing a query, the results are readonly and we can't delete/update any records from the results grid.

and on the other side, if we right click a table and choose Edit top (1000), then show the SQL pane, there is no Intellisense support nor you can Join with other tables to improve the data displayed.

so the question is, is there any way to improve any of the above two?
because this would be much better in productivity.

thanks!

Comment: i know already that mostly there is no solution for both, but hey, maybe there is :)
and also i would prefer answers different than converting the query to a view first, because we are talking about productivity and on the fly queries.

Comment: Are you really editing data "by hand" that frequently that this is an issue for you?

Comment: If you want to use JOINs it will be difficult to "understand" which table do you want to edit. There is no magic here. There is an alternative way - to convert resultsgrid into "update-where" statements, so you can enter new data and run X update queries.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, kind of yes.

Comment: @AndreiRantsevich, thanks, but i would prefer if there is a direct way.

sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

I use Microsoft Access and attached tables linked to an ODBC datasource for exactly the kind of interaction you are  describing.

Comment: but how would i do this in my case?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. In the past, I've created Access dbs that have links to tables in my SQL database - [tutorial](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1480/configure-microsoft-access-linked-tables-with-a-sql-server-database) - I use the query editor to create updateable data views - you must keep your joins simple. If I know I'll be making little tweaks to the data, I'll take the time to set this up. But I've been using Access since 1994 so I'm very comfortable with it. Your experience might be quite different if you're not used to way it processes queries.